# Is there any other way to set Task.Status to Cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

Ok, so I understand how to do Task cancellations using `CancellationTokenSource`. it appears to me that the `Task` type "kind of" handles this exception automatically - it sets the `Task`'s `Status` to Cancelled.

Now you still actually have to handle the `OperationCancelledException`. Otherwise the exception bubbles up to `Application.UnhandledException`. The Task itself kind of recognizes it and does some handling internally, but you still need to wrap the calling code in a try block to avoid the unhandled exception. Sometimes, this seems like unnecessary code. If the user presses cancel, then cancel the `Task` (obviously the task itself needs to handle it too). I don't feel like there needs to be any other code requirement. Simply check the `Status` property for the completion status of the task.

Is there any specific reason for this from a language design point of view?  Is there any other way to set the `Status` property to cancelled?

Answer (score 6):

You can set a Task's status to cancelled without a `CancellationToken` if you create it using `TaskCompletionSource`

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
var task = tcs.Task;
tcs.SetCancelled();
```

Other than that you can only cancel a running `Task` with a `CancellationToken`

Comment: Interesting... I will have a look into this, although Jon's answer has altered my thinking a bit.

Comment: @Simon Jon Skeet's answer is of course correct. This is probably a case of [The XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @l3arnon - Brilliant - that's exactly my problem! The Y problem, ah I mean the X....eh :)

Answer (score 4):

You only need to wrap the calling code in a try/catch block where you're asking for the result, or waiting for the task to complete - those are the situations in which the exception is thrown. The code *creating* the task won't throw that exception, for example.

It's not clear what the alternative would be - for example:

```
string x = await GetTaskReturningString();
```

Here we never have a variable referring to the task, so we can't explicitly check the status. We'd have to use:

```
var task = GetTaskReturningString();
string x = await task;
if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
{
    ...
}
```

... which is not only less convenient, but *also* moves the handling of the "something happened" code into the middle of the normal success path.

Additionally, by handling cancellation with an exception, if you have several operations, you can put all the handling in one catch block instead of checking each task separately:

```
try
{
    var x = await GetFirstTask();
    var y = await GetSecondTask(x);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    // We don't care which was canceled
}
```

The same argument applies for handling cancellation in *one* place wherever in the stack the first cancellation occurred - if you have a deep stack of async methods, cancellation in the deepest method will result in the top-most task being canceled, just like normal exception propagation.

Comment: thanks. The second part of your answer clears (and explains) the design decisions and reasoning. Now I agree that the try/catch method is probably cleaner than my original thinking. However, I cannot see why I dont have to wrap the calling code in the try block - if I don't the `OperationCancelledException` will crash the application?

Comment: @Simon: My point is that it's not the code that *starts* the task that needs to be wrapped - only the code that waits for the result... and even then, only at a top level. Will clarify.

Comment: I think I understand the scenario!